# Is "deficitary" an admissible word?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives

Is the word "deficitary" (meaning "having some deficit") admissible?

Although it does not appear as an entry in most of the standard dictionaries (Merriam-Webster, Cambridge,...) it seems to be used quite often in many reputable books and media.

Is it ok to use it (in particular, if it is used with a precisely stated meaning in a technical context)? Concretely, I would like to call "deficitary" any state in a deterministic automaton which does not have every possible transition departing it. Even more precisely, if some state is lacking one particular kind of transition (say *a*) I would like to call it *a*-deficitary.

If not, which would be appropriate alternatives?

Comment: *Deficient* https://www.thefreedictionary.com/deficient should work in general English writing. *Deficitary is jargon.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain (1) what you mean by 'admissible' – using it might lose you a few friends and (2) enlarge upon 'Concretely a state in an automaton is said to be "deficitary" if it does not have every ...

Comment: possible transition departing it.'?  There must be an agent 'saying' this. I've found 'Those patients whom we might define as "deficitary" ...' in ['The Girl who Committed Hara-Kiri and Other Clinical and Historical Essays'_ by Franco Borgogno](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bQlQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT80&lpg=PT80&dq=automaton+%22deficitary%22&source=bl&ots=W1nbmacHXV&sig=ACfU3U1kZsdCMbPTofaZBNoWOWiQTOQiUw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK2IbxzsHmAhWWgVwKHdl4CNcQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=automaton%20%22deficitary%22&f=false). This indicates that even subject-specific usages are deemed to need scare-quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Kris, I discarded "deficient" because of its negative connotations. I'd just like to neutrally acknowledge that not every possible case is achieved (without any positive or negative connotation).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (1) by "admissible" I mean not wrong enough to be inappropriate for publication in a regular journal (2) the context is that of automata theory in theoretical computer science.

Comment: (2) ... I edited the question with more details on the context and the intended meaning for "deficitary".

Comment: '[B]y "admissible" I mean not wrong enough to be inappropriate for publication in a regular journal' marks this as outside the scope of standard English usage (you need to check with editors qas to their views).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a word that is not in common usage, and which cannot be easily found in the most popular dictionaries, then even if it *is* a real word (perhaps an archaic one), you have to then think about how your audience will receive and understand it. Will they struggle to find a definition and give up? As a native English speaker, I think your audience is more likely to *assume* a definition, because English speakers 'make up' words all the time - for example, portmanteaus like "fantabulous" - and we recognise them for what they are because there is a degree of familiarity in it. So what would someone likely assume "deficitiary" means?

If a *beneficiary* is someone who *derives* or *receives* benefit from something, then it would seem logical that a *deficitary* (if such a word exists) would not be someone who is *in* deficit, but someone who somehow is put into deficit by someone or something else; for example an inherited debt.

As there are other words which suggest a general deficiency or lack, such as "deficient", "bereft", "wanting", I suspect that using "deficitary" would miss what you were trying to say anyway.

Comment: Just in case, the answer to your (probably rhetorical) fist question is that no reader will struggle because any non-standard concept will be precisely defined within the text. My main concern is to make things sound natural: to use a word which is not incorrect (the less sophisticated the better), and whose standard meaning applies better to the notion I want to introduce.

Comment: @suitangi It's not a 'standard word' so it can't have a standard (default) meaning.

Comment: @suitangi Well, to be clear - I don't think it is a word. I trawled the internet and I literally found just one person saying it on Twitter. That doesn't make it real.